# App Inventor 2 Location Sensor Stopped Working

Tags: android, location, maps, app-inventor, android-gps

I am working on a scavenger hunt type app for a class project and need to use the location sensor to trigger events during game play. I watched tutorials online to get the latitude, longitude, and current address displayed in a text label. I had it working well enough about a week ago. But, when I tried to show the progress I had made to my teammates, the location sensor would not update the text label to the lat long of the user or the current address.

Since then, I have been unable to get it to work on this project or any test project.  I have been using the AI Companion with my LG-G5 and with the emulator with similar results. The LG-G5 is using the GPS and Networks to get phone location and I can see that the AI2 Companion is requesting location info from the phone. I would understand more if it just didn't work at all but it worked temporarily and then not at all.

If anyone has an idea about how to get this working again, I would be super grateful.

[Codeblocks for getting lat and long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlAfg.png)
[image]

Comment: make sure to be at least close to a window or better go outside to get the best GPS signal...also make sure, that GPS is enabled... see also the Get Available SSID project here https://puravidaapps.com/wifi.php

Answer (score 0):

If you found that everything worked 100% for a short time and now doesn't work at all, if you've performed a restart of the equipment but still doesn't work, I'd consider that you may have a bad component somewhere. It was good in the beginning but extended use has caused it to fail.

Comment: I got it working! The settings on the phone where interfering with the Location Sensor function. If anyone is having issues like this one, on your phone, try going into Settings -> Location -> Mode -> and change the Location Mode to "Networks Only". I did this and I got the Lat, Long, and Addresses to populate.